# How to create private factory in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am using factory for myapp , is it possible to create a private factory in angular js.

```
module.factory('ParentService', function ($q, $http) {
  return {
//public API
 };
});



module.factory('ChildService', function (ParentService, $sce) {
   var child = Object.create(ParentService);
   child.childMethod = function () {
//extending the parent
};
return child;
});
```

I want my ParentService to be private so that no other controller have the access to it.

Comment: If there is no such provision, is it possible to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create them in AngularJS 1.x. In future there may be module-scoped services/factories but nobody has implemented them yet.